# Telegram бот, не работает проверка на админа

Tags: python, asyncio

Учусь в написании Telegram бота на Aiogram 3.4.1 (Python 3.8.1). В боте предусмотрена Reply клавиатура, которая должна отображаться только админу, чей ID лежит в файле .env
Чтобы каждый раз в обработчиках не писать проверку на админа, написал функцию:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

async def isadmin(message: Message):
    if message.from_user.id == int(os.getenv('ADMIN')):
        return True
```

К сожалению, при следующем вызове ...

```
@router.message(F.text == content.schedule_control_BT)
async def schedule_control(message: Message):
    if isadmin(message):
        await message.answer('ok', reply_markup=kba.schedule)
```

... проверка не производится, появляется ошибка:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'isadmin' was never awaited   if
> isadmin(message): RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object
> allocation traceback

Что нужно исправить?

Comment: Это прямо типичная ошибка при использовании асинхронных функций. В ошибке буквально написано, что корутина isadmin не была "awaited", это означает что вы забыли поставить await перед ней при ее вызове. Должно быть `if await isadmin(message):`

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вопрос решен, был невнимателен

Comment: Решение добавьте ответом, в вопросе должен быть только вопрос

Comment: Ок, добавил. Спасибо за помощь еще раз)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился подстановкой *await* перед вызовом функции *isadmin*

```
@router.message(F.text == content.schedule_control_BT)
async def schedule_control(message: Message):
    if await isadmin(message):
        await message.answer('ok', reply_markup=kba.schedule)
```

Благодарю за помощь участника сообщества [insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365/insolor)

Comment: К слову, было бы логичнее сделать функцию `isadmin()` блокирующей (убрать `async` при объявлении и, соответственно, `await` при вызове). В этой функции все равно нет ничего асинхронного, а написание `async` просто так может запутать в будущем.

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, если убрать асинхронность из функции isadmin(), почему она станет блокирующей? И что это значит? Если скинете ссылки с информацией на эту тему на почитать  - заранее спасибо!

Comment: Текста много вышло, вы можете прочитать ответ в чате: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152283/async-in-python-dicussion

Comment: Стас, было очень интересно прочитать ваше объяснение! Спасибо! p.s. книгу O'Reilly скачал)